# Intersects array empty in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to set a different color to an object, which I selected in Three JS. I am getting the x and y position of the mouse, but the function raycaster.intersectObjects() always returns an empty array.

I am loading the data here and filling the objects array:

```
var objects = [];
var mousev,raycaster, scene, renderer, controls, loader;

//Load Data
    loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load("models/selectableObjects.json", function (obj) {
        scene.add(obj);
        scene.traverse(function(children){
            objects.push(children);
        });
    },
        function (xhr) {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
        },

        function (err) {
            console.error('An error happened');
        }
    );
```

That's my mouse down Event listener:

```
        raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        mousev = new THREE.Vector2();
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

    function onDocumentMouseDown(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        mousev.x = (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
        console.log("Mouse position X: "+mousev.x);
        mousev.y = (event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;
        console.log("Mouse position Y: "+mousev.y);

        raycaster.setFromCamera( mousev, camera );
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
        console.log("Objects: ");
        console.log(objects);
        console.log("Intersects: ");
        console.log(intersects);

        var color = (Math.random() * 0xffffff);

        for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
            intersects[i].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the material double-sided? Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647131/raycasting-doesnt-give-any-intersections), it might help.

Comment: I notice it's similar to the demo code [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster) - is it possible you missed the negative sign in mouse.y?

Comment: Thank you that was the problem. I missed the negative sign.